Flutter iOS Project - Xcode Provisioning Profile Issues
I'm experiencing a problem when creating an iOS project in Flutter. When I open the project with Xcode and try to compile it, I encounter the following issues related to provisioning:
"Your development team has reached the maximum number of registered iPhone devices."
"Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'xxx.Runner'."

However, any other project that I have or create from scratch using Xcode compiles correctly without these signing errors.
Has anyone encountered this issue before, or does anyone know how to resolve it? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Have you registered for the Apple Developer Program yet? If you have, then Apple allows you to add 100 iPhone devices each year. If you use a free account, you are only allowed to add 5 devices and build on those 5 devices.

"However, any other project that I have or create from scratch using Xcode compiles correctly without these signing errors."
